# How to read server response when calling push/pushSelected methods from Worklight JSONStore?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I`m trying to find out how to get the server response when I call the JSONStore push/pushSelected functions.
I know that I can handle succes using:

```
.then(function (res) {
    //handle success
    //res is an empty array if all documents reached the server
    //res is an array of error responses if some documents failed to reach the server
})
```

But what I really want is to read the server response, that has important information for me.

I even tried using an onSuccess callback (below code), but it didn't work too.

```
var options = {
    onSuccess: function(response){
        WL.Logger.debug("response: "+JSON.stringify(response));
    }
};
myCollection.pushSelected(doc, options)
.then(function (res){
     ...
});
```

It prints "response: 0"

Is there a way that I can do that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the response from the adapter in the accept function.

> accept: function (adapterResponse) { return (adapterResponse.status
>   === 200); }

There's an example in the [WL.JSONStore.init](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_init.html) documentation page.

If you want something else, I suggest a [feature request](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014907906&ps=25).

Comment: It worked! Thanks. What I did was use a global variable to keep a response value that i need, and reference it after calling 'pushSelected'.